# subtracting arrays in numpy and plotting with pylab

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a simple text file composed of 8 columns and I read it with loadtxt function. I want to plot as x-axis column6-column7 and as y-axis column7-column8 so I put this command

```
>>> pl.plot(np.subtract(data2[:,6], data2[:7]), np.subtract(data2[:,7], data2[:,8]))
and it gave this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (59427) (7,9)
```

What is the problem? and how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data2[:7]` should be `data2[:,7]` -- you missed a comma.
`data2[:7]` apparently has shape (7,9), while `data2[:,6]` has shape (50427,). The error message is saying that the two arrays can not be broadcasted to a common shape upon which `np.subtract` can be applied.

```
x = data2[:,6] - data2[:,7]
y = data2[:,7] - data2[:,8]
pl.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: @user2154410 If this solved your problem please accept it (big gray check box on the left)